# Is there a way to implement a LightGBM model into R without access to the LightGBM package?

Tags: python, r, model, implementation, lightgbm

For my use case I do not have the luxury of having access to the R version of the LightGBM package. I'd like to implement a trained model into a platform that can use R but does NOT have access to the LightGBM package.

For example, something analogous to this would be handy: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm2sas/gbm2sas.pdf

Which one can basically creates a brute-force "if-else-then" script logic to aggregate up the marginal predictions into SAS code. Is there something like a "lightgbm2R" package out there that creates an "R script" for the "if-then-else" logic?

I've also looked into outputting the model into a JSON and importing it into R that way, too, but there doesn't seem to be a way to pass predictions into the model without access to LightGBM's *predict* function using the R's lightgbm package.

I do have access to R's **gbm** package, however. Is there a way this package could possibly import a LightGBM trained model file? The platform also has access to Python (but again no access to the LightGBM package). I know you can output the model file to a dataframe (i.e. "*trees_to_dataframe()*", but I have no idea how to pass the model features to this dataframe to get a prediction. If there's an example out there that shows how to do this (again, without leveraging the LightGBM package) that would also work.

I REALLY do not want to manually code in "if-then-else" logic for the tree. I was hoping there would be some sort of "standard" for exporting/importing serialized model objects across platforms (such as how JSON is a standard that is recognized across many platforms), but I can't seem to find such a thing for tree models.

In summary, the question is this: Is there a way to get a prediction from a LightGBM model file in either R or Python WITHOUT access to the LightGBM package that does not involve manually coding in the "if-then-else" tree logic?

Thank you for your time,
SYL

Comment: In general I would recommend using the parsnip libraries of the tidymodels framework: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/08/how-to-use-lightgbm-with-tidymodels/

Comment: That article recommends using `{treesnip}`, which requires the `{lightgbm}`, so it isn't an option under the constraint "no access to the LightGBM package".

Comment: Do you have access to xgboost? If so, setting the parameters `tree_method` to "hist" and `grow_policy` to "lossguide" will emulate lightgbm. Note these are the python parameters. The R parameters tend to have a . instead of an _

Comment: Unfortunately no access to XGBoost either. Sounds like there is no easy answer here and I’ll have to put in the work to implement something else. I was hoping to avoid being clever, but apparently I’ll have to be. 
I appreciate the answers, the emulation of LGB in XGB is cool to know.

Comment: There are many other options for converting LightGBM models, listed at https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM#external-unofficial-repositories. I just wasn't sure which to suggest since I'm not sure exactly what the limitations you face are.

Comment: Holy smokes this is a gold mine, thank you. 

Limitation is basically just a way to implement a trained/tuned model into an environment that has Python and R, but little access to libraries to add onto. Something like the gbm2sas example would work, which basically creates a SAS script using “if-then-else” logic for the features to navigate down for implementation for models trained from R’s GBM package. 

I’m relatively new to the deployment side of these models, so apologies if the answer is obvious.